# node-sass configuration not rendering stylesheets to page (express)

Tags: node.js, express, sass

I'm having trouble rendering stylesheets to the page in my node app using the [node-sass library](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass). The server returns 200, and I can inspect the `main.scss` using dev tools, but the content page is not actually modified.

I have already made sure that the `express.static` directive comes **after** `sass.middleware`, and added `sass.render` (now removed) inside of my one route to attempt to error log. It returned no error. Also, `index.html` contains `<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.scss">`. Any help is greatly appreciated!

directories:

```
├── app.js
├── launch.sh
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── index.html                                                                                                                                          
│   └── stylesheets                                                                    
│       └── main.scss                                                                     
└── spec                                                                                  
    ├── unit.js                                                                           
    └── unitExamples.js
```

app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    sass    = require('node-sass'),
    path    = require('path'),
    app     = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.urlencoded());
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(
    sass.middleware({
      src: __dirname + '/public/stylesheets',
      dest: __dirname + '/public/',
      debug: true,
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
    })
  );
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be referencing the *target* `css` file, not its source:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
```

Also, SCSS files should not be accessible from the outside world, so they should be moved out of `public`.

Comment: Ok, so the piece that I didn't understand was that `main.scss` should in fact compile to `main.css` in `public`. Problem solved. Thanks, that's very helpful!

Comment: Would love to, but my reputation isn't high enough yet to upvote!